# Is it safe to run a full system backup with tar on an ext4 filesystem?

Tags: backup, tar

I'd like to make a backup of a live system, I'm running the command `tar -cvpzf backup-latest.tar.gz --exclude=/backup-latest.tar.gz --one-file-system /`

But I just got an error of: `tar: /: file changed as we read it` - I'm unsure if it's dropped any files or the backup succeeded.

I'm not too concerned about file permissions - just the file data most importantly.

Comment: `--one-file-system` is designed to skip things. (for example, a `/dev` populated with static device nodes would be skipped, in some cases this is still required for successful booting). For a *full* backup of the rootfs, you can `mount --bind / /mnt/root` then backup `/mnt/root` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 2):

- It is not safe to do this on a life filesystem, better create a snapshot before you backup the data. How a snapshot is created and whether it is supported depends on the filesystem type, so I cannot give you an advise since you did not mention the filesystem you are using.
- From your command line arguments, it seems that you use `gtar`.  This tar implementation sometimes has problems in reading it's own archives...so be careful to verify the archive you created for readability.
- Note that the command line you use does not allow you to archive more than the basic meta data and only archives time stamps with a one second granularity.
- Meta data that would be missing is: ACLs, extended attributes, ...
- A POSIX.1-1988 tar archive is able to archive directories, files, hard links, symlinks, block special, character special, named pipes. The fact that it cannot archive sockets is not a problem. So `tar` in general is not a problem.

Comment: Also, special files (device nodes, sockets, named pipes etc.) might not get properly stored, AFAIK. And hard links...

Comment: Before 1988, this has been a problem with the tar format

Answer (score 0):

Seems, like and awful old school way of making a backup. Is this a real server and not a VM? If it's a VM, VEEAm comes to mind as does ghetto backup.  If it's a real server what file system are you using brts uses snapshots as does lvm. Since your doing a tar, maybe you can rsync your data to another box?

Comment: No, "old school" would be to use `dump`.  Using `tar` to make a full system backup is just showing that they are not aware of proper backup software.

Comment: Using `dump` is indeed old school as it shows that somebody does not yet know that `star` is able to to the same as `dump` in a filesystem and OS independend way since 14 years, but faster than `dump`.